# Service not defining when injecting it for Karma testing - AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, testing, gulp, karma-jasmine

I've seen a few of these questions on the internet, but none of the answers seem to solve my problem. I have a service that works perfectly in my served app, but when I test it in Karma it is not being defined.

I've got my modules and associated controllers, directives and services in a `src` folder. The structure of this file is as follows:

```
angular.module('cst-error-framework', ['md.alerts', 'md.input', 'md.modals']);

angular.module('md.alerts', [])
    .directive(//..associated directives here

angular.module('md.input', [])
    //blah blah blah

angular.module('md.modals', [])
    //directives and controllers

   .factory('mdErrorHandler', function () {
        //contents here
    });
```

I know this seems a bit cumbersome but there are other reasons I have this in one file.

Then my spec for `mdErrorHandler` is as follows:

```
describe('Service errorHandler', function () {

beforeEach(function() {
    module('cst-error-framework');
    angular.mock.module('templates');
});
var mdErrorHandler;

beforeEach(inject(function(_mdErrorHandler_){
    mdErrorHandler = _mdErrorHandler_;
    console.log(mdErrorHandler);
}));
```

Here is my `karma.conf.js`:

```
module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({

   basePath: '',

   frameworks: ['jasmine'],

   files: [
     'bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js',
     'bower_components/angular/angular.js',
     'bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js',
     'bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',

     'dist/cst-error-framework.js',
     'dist/cst-error-framework.css',

     'src/**/templates/*.html',
     'src/helpers/*.js',
     'src/**/test/*.spec.js'
    ],

   preprocessors : {
     'src/**/templates/*.html': 'ng-html2js'
   },

   ngHtml2JsPreprocessor: {
     stripPrefix: 'src/',
     moduleName: 'templates'
   },

   exclude: [],

   port: 9876,

   logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,

   autoWatch: true,

   browsers: [process.env.TRAVIS ? 'Firefox' : 'Chrome'],

   singleRun: false
  });
  'use strict';
  };
```

Then when I run the karma tests, my `mdErrorHandler` is not being defined, so the result of my `console.log` is just `[]`.

Any idea what's going on? Is it something to do with the order with which Karma is loading stuff? Would like to avoid having to completely refactor my main `.js` file.

*EDIT*
Starting to suspect that maybe something in my gulpfile is causing issues? Here is my Karma Gulp task:

```
gulp.task('karma', ['build'], function(done) {
 karma.start({
   configFile: __dirname + '/karma.conf.js',
   singleRun: true
 }, done);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

When you instantiate the module in your test, you don't need the function declaration.

So instead of

```
beforeEach(function() {
    module('cst-error-framework');
    angular.mock.module('templates');
});
```

try

```
beforeEach(module('cst-error-framework');
beforeEach(angular.mock.module('templates');
```

Comment: Thanks, that's a good point. However I made this change and still have the same issue. Have now included some Gulpfile information in the question.

Comment: This worked for me. But I also needed to do
   beforeEach(inject(function($injector){
      mdErrorHandler = $injector.get('mdErrorHandler');
      console.log(mdErrorHandler);
   }));
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to run your test suite, you must put atleast single expectation in your test suite.

```
describe('Service errorHandler', function() {

    beforeEach(function() {
        module('cst-error-framework');
        console.log(1);
    });
    var mdErrorHandler;

    beforeEach(inject(function(_mdErrorHandler_) {
        mdErrorHandler = _mdErrorHandler_;
        console.log(mdErrorHandler);

    }));

    it('do for nothing', function() {
        expect(true).toBe(true);
    })
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I know this, I was just illustrating the setup, which is the bit that's failing.